# Android Libgdx Could not reserve enough space for 1536000KB object heap

Tags: java, android, memory, libgdx, jvm

For the first time I am using Libgdx.

I can download and unzip finished. But error occured

> Unable to start daemon process
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for 1536000KB object heap

[image]

In Android studio I got same problem. But I can Change it by

gradle.properties----> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m

Then it works fine. But in libgdx, I don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a System Variables in your Environment Variables of your System.

```
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Xmx512M
```

Give a Restart to your System.

Comment: What's your​ system RAM memory, 32 or 64 bit processor, Is your JDK architecture​ same as your processor.

Comment: 4GB RAM and 32 bit processor

Comment: How to check JDK architecture

Comment: It will 32 bit because on 32 bit processor you can't install 64 bit JDK

Comment: Yes solved. I just Change Java options. Then restart  computer. Problem solved!!!

Comment: It's great, Glad to hear that.